# WCF Timeout (HTTP Request was aborted/No endpoint listening)

Tags: silverlight, wcf, timeout

I was modifying a WCF service to increase the timeout for a Silverlight client. Before modifying the timeouts I'm seeing CommunicationObjectAborted exception (The HTTP request to [URL] was aborted). At first I only modified the web.coffig of the WCF and it had no effect. I then followed this post ([http://blog.ecofic.com/?p=379](http://blog.ecofic.com/?p=37)) and edited ServiceReferences.ClientConfig as well. Now I'm seeing a No endpoint exception. The exception was not thrown immediately after the client connects to WCF, but after about 1 minute after it connected to WCF. I suspect it has something to do with the timeouts?

I set open, close, send and receive timeouts to 5 minutes in both config files.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: After some testing, I found out the timeout settings on server side (web.config) seems to have no effect. I got the same exception (endpoint not found) if I remove the timeout settings from web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard pointed out, sendTimeout only be needed to set on the client (your Windows Phone app in this case). Double check the ServiceReferences.clientConfig as manually added value might get overwritten by Visual Studio.

Also you can check [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx) for using Fiddler on Windows Phone (emulator).

Comment: Thanks for the fiddler advice. The sendTimeout is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fiddler to analyse the requests performed by your application. This way, you will be able to know what happen when the request is sent, where exactly it is sent (if it is sent), and the response code from the server.

Obtaining these informations is the first step on the way to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I'm sure the request did get sent out by the client and to the correct endpoint (no matter with what timeout settings). Now I'm suspecting there might be something with WCF that closes the endpoint after one minute. So even no timeout was hit, the endpoint was gone and therefore the "endpoint not found" exception.

Comment: Also another interesting point is, according to some posts on MSDN, in most cases only sendTimeout need to be increased. However, increasing the timeout has no effect (same CommunicationObjectAborted exception).

Comment: sendTimeout is a sender configuration value and only needs to be set on the client in this case. Are you sure your increased send timeout was getting picked up? After creating the proxy look at the binding and see what the sendTimeout is set to

Comment: Could you provide some hints on how can I verify the sendTimeout value? I used Fiddler but didn't see any relative information (or perhaps I missed it). The client is a Silverlight app running on WP7. Thanks!